# When are EvaluationNotebook[] and ButtonNotebook[] different?

Tags: notebooks, gui-construction, palettes

I am looking for a concrete code example where `EvaluationNotebook[]` and `ButtonNotebook[]` will return different results.

The docs for `ButtonNotebook` say:

> If a button in a palette initiates evaluation in another notebook,
>   then `ButtonNotebook[]` will be the palette, but `EvaluationNotebook[]`
>   will be the other notebook.

How can a palette button initiate an evaluation in a different notebook?

A basic test where they return the same (the palette):

```
CreatePalette[
 Button["press", Print@{EvaluationNotebook[], ButtonNotebook[]}]]
```

I am looking for an example where `EvaluationNotebook` and `ButtonNotebook` return different results *when invoked from the same button*.  Of course `ButtonNotebook` will return `$Failed` when not invoked from a button.

---

**Addendum**

I'd like to point out that this question is not merely of theoretical interest.  The fact that `ButtonNotebook` exists at all suggests that it must be different from `EvaluationNotebook` in some non-trivial way.  Understanding the behaviour of `EvaluationNotebook`/`ButtonNotebook` is important to create robust code that will work correctly in edge cases too.  I can not see their difference, so there must be some edge case I have not thought of.

Comment: I know this is not your real question, but for starters, `ButtonNotebook[]` returns `$Failed` in a fresh notebook and `EvaluationNotebook[]` doesn't

Comment: There's even an example in the `EvaluationNotebook` docs of your point where they use `EvaluationNotebook` to refer to the button notebook: `pal = CreatePalette[{Button["Test",     NotebookWrite[InputNotebook[], "Done"]; 
     NotebookClose[ EvaluationNotebook[]]]}];`

Comment: @Rojo That's of course the trivial difference.  I didn't mention it because I thought it was clear that I'm interested in the case when the code is invoked from a button.

Comment: Not everyone may know you're advanced, the first sentence could clarify that last point of yours

Answer (score 5):

John Fultz posted an answer to this question [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/38613). Apparently, in this context, both `ButtonNotebook` and `EvaluationNotebook` are identical. The former is kept around for legacy purposes, but the latter is preferable because it is applicable in places other than in buttons.