# Understanding the difference between EvaluationNotebook and ButtonNotebook (and their FrontEnd` versions)

Tags: front-end, dynamic, evaluation, notebooks, documentation

The Documentation for `ButtonNotebook` says:

> 1. `ButtonNotebook[]` gives the notebook, if any, that contains the button which initiated the current evaluation.
> 2. If a button in a palette initiates evaluation in another notebook, then `ButtonNotebook[]` will be the palette, but `EvaluationNotebook[]` will be the other notebook.
> 3. If the current evaluation was not initiated by a button, then `ButtonNotebook[]` will return `$Failed`.

These statements raise several questions. The first is:

### 1. What is "a button"?

Obviously it isn't *only* `Button` because `Dynamic[ButtonNotebook[]]` doesn't display `$Failed`:

```
Dynamic[ButtonNotebook[]]
```

[image: screenshot]

The same is true when `ButtonNotebook[]` is evaluated as a part of `CellDynamicExpression`:

```
CellPrint@ExpressionCell[Dynamic@bnb, "Output", 
  CellDynamicExpression :> (bnb = ButtonNotebook[])]
```

[image: screenshot]

... or as a part of `Initialization` in `DynamicModule`:

```
DynamicModule[{bnb}, {Dynamic[bnb]}, Initialization :> (bnb = ButtonNotebook[])]
```

[image: screenshot]

So, **what is assumed under "button" *exactly*?**

### 2. What is "evaluation"?

Consider the following example from the Documentation page for `Button`:

```
Button["Front End", SelectionMove[ButtonNotebook[], All, ButtonCell], Evaluator -> None]
```

[image: screenshot]

From this example it is clear that **evaluation may happen in the FrontEnd *only***, i.e. without any interaction with the Kernel, and `ButtonNotebook[]` will correctly refer to the corresponding Notebook. At least this point looks clearly documented.

### 3. When `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` are different?

The statement number 2 cited at the beginning of this question "describes" a situation when `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` are different, but no examples are given on the corresponding Documentation pages. Let us try to construct an example according to the description:

```
Button["Evaluate new notebook",
 nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer@Pause[1], "Input"]]; 
 SelectionMove[nb, All, CellContents]; SelectionEvaluate[nb];
 Print[{nb, ButtonNotebook[], EvaluationNotebook[]}]]
```

> [image: output]

After clicking the button the following gets printed:

[image: screenshot]

Both `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` return the same `NotebookObject`. But may be we simply haven't fulfilled the requirement that the button should be "in a palette"? But what means "a palette"? The tutorial "[Creating Palettes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingPalettes.html)" suggests `CreatePalette` as the primary tool to create them, so let's try:

```
ourNotebook = EvaluationNotebook[];
CreatePalette@Button["Evaluate new notebook",
  nb = CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer@Pause[1], "Input"]]; 
  SelectionMove[nb, All, CellContents]; SelectionEvaluate[nb];
  NotebookWrite[ourNotebook, ToBoxes@{nb, ButtonNotebook[], EvaluationNotebook[]}]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Again, both `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` refer to the palette Notebook and not to the Notebook where the button initiated evaluation (which is still running when `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` are evaluated themselves).

So the main question remains completely unclear: **in which situations `ButtonNotebook[]` and `EvaluationNotebook[]` return different `NotebookObject`s?**

Comment: Relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7523/12

Comment: I would trust [John Fultz's answer](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/38613) more than the documentation ...

Comment: So the main question is a duplicate, and the answer is never, they are the same, right? Only 2. remains.

Comment: @Kuba I think **1.** also remains because potentially we can use `ButtonNotebook[]` for testing whether we are in a "button" or not.

Comment: `SelectedNotebook[]` and `ButtonNotebook[]` are not equivalent here : `{
Button["SelectedNotebook Red",SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[],Background-> RGBColor[1,0,0]]],
Button["ButtonNotebook Red",SetOptions[ButtonNotebook[],Background-> RGBColor[1,0,0]]],
Button["Reset to White",SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[],Background-> RGBColor[1,1,1]];SetOptions[ButtonNotebook[],Background-> RGBColor[1,1,1]]]
} //CreatePalette`.